# Laravel 8 - "load" method ignores deleted status of related records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a $bubble object that have many people related. In some cases I must remove that people so I delete it (with soft delete). So, thats ok. But when I get the people of this bubble with lazy load, it return all people, active and deleted.
I need only active people (not deleted).

(Edit: I have a pivot table that have the deleted_at column)

I do:

```
$bubble->load('people');
```

dd output:

```
dd($bubble->people);

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1614 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Models\People {#1628 ▶} // Was delete (has date in daleted_at column)
    1 => App\Models\People {#1629 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\People {#1630 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Edit II:

Model: Bubble

```
class Bubble extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    public function peoples()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(People::class, 'bubble_people');
    }

}
```

Model People

```
class People extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;
    public function bubbles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Bubble::class, 'bubble_people');
    }
}
```

Controller People

```
public function show(People $people)
{
    $people->bubbles->load('peoples');
    return view('people.show', compact('people'));
}
```

View

```
@foreach ($people->bubbles as $b)
        @foreach ($b->peoples as $p)
               <!-- print data -->
        @endforeach
        
@endforeach
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: public function people()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Users')->where('status','Active')->whereNull('deleted_at');
    }

Comment: Can you share ``Bubble`` and ``Person`` models?

Comment: if you are using the trait it should cast them automatically can you share your relations ?

Comment: I'v added te rest of code. @YunusKocabay with your way works well but not shure if there are any way implicit for all situations.